# Getting ElementNotInteractableException error in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error when i am trying to enter a text to a text field by fetching the data from an Excel sheet.

```java
Error Message : Error while entering the text in DOM! Element <input id="Name" class="flipperMozEdit" name="Name" type="text"> is not reachable by keyboard
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'G5CG7133385E', ip: '10.181.210.46', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\502457528\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.6Sn2RalXsr0R, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=XP, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=62.0.3, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=14160, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, moz:webdriverClick=true}]
Session ID: 1ea9a987-f329-464f-adac-af2b92064a1d
```

I have tried the below code :
Element

```html
    <input type="text" value="" name="Name" id="Name" onfocus="FullSearch.displayDynamicTextarea(this)" size="30%" delimiter="|" class="flipperMozView">
```

```java
    @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='Name']")
    public WebElement txt_NameMR;


    BaseClass.waitForObj(10000);
    BaseClass.set(txt_NameMR,ExcelReport.testData.get("ownerName")+"*");
    BaseClass.waitForObj(5000);
    BaseClass.click(btn_Srch_Name);
```

This is the Element for txt_NameMR

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Name" id="Name" onfocus="FullSearch.displayDynamicTextarea(this)" size="30%" delimiter="|" class="flipperMozView">
```

Comment: You're not showing enough of your code for me to be able to make any useful comments, there's too many questions I would have to ask.  You're using `@FindBy` which implies pagefactory, but I don't see that code, I don't see BaseClass at all, don't know what the shown class is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element is intractable.
txt_NameMR.click(); // This usually activate the element in DOM.

```
  BaseClass.waitForObj(10000);
     txt_NameMR.click();   BaseClass.set(txt_NameMR,ExcelReport.testData.get("ownerName")+"*");
        BaseClass.waitForObj(5000);
        BaseClass.click(btn_Srch_Name);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after providing .click();

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <input 
    id="NAME" class="flipperMozEdit" name="NAME" type="text"> is not reachable by keyboard
   Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'

Comment: @jyothisharma i guess the element is either disabled or refreshed. can you share the html page source. ? We can look at if there is any other ways to interact with the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have a guess based on the info provided.  I'm assuming you are trying to use page objects using the Java PageFactory implementation, so I think you need the following.

**Page Object**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class MyPageObject {
    @FindBy(id = "Name")
    WebElement txt_NameMR;

    @FindBy(id = "<ID_OF_Search_Button>")
    WebElement btn_Srch_Name;

    WebDriverWait wait;

    public MyPageObject(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
    }

    public void searchFor(String text){
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(txt_NameMR)).sendKeys(text);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(btn_Srch_Name)).click();
    }
}
```

**Main Code (That calls the page object)**

```
MyPageObject myPageObject = new MyPageObject(driver);
myPageObject.searchFor(ExcelReport.testData.get("ownerName")+"*");
```

Now you may still have problems with waits here, the page object is going to wait until an element is clickable, but since the explicit wait is taking in a WebElement, if you don't have that element on the page when the explicit wait is triggered you will see a `NoSuchElement` exception.  You can fix this with a more targeted explicit wait like this:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Name")));
```

There is no easy way to get the locator (By object) out of a Java PageFactory WebElement though so you have some code duplication.  This is one of the reasons I created my [Query library](https://github.com/ardesco/query) which helps you get around problems like this.