# Page Object Model Selenium, adding a wait into a test class

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I have tried, at the bottom, to create waiting method for a web element and then I declare it in the test class and it does not work. What would be the best way of adding a wait? I wish to declare a wait after the postcode box has been filled in

Page Object

```
    package pageFactory;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ECUTestform {
    WebDriverWait wait; 
    WebDriver driver;



    public ECUTestform(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 50);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);

    }


@FindBy(id="RegisterModel_Phone")
WebElement phone;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"RegisterModel_Name\"]")
WebElement firstname;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"RegisterModel_Address\"]")
WebElement addressone;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"RegisterModel_Street\"]")
WebElement addresstwo;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"RegisterModel_City\"]")
WebElement city;

@FindBy(id="RegisterModel_Email")
WebElement email;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"RegisterModel_ConfirmEmail\"]")
WebElement emailconfirm;

@FindBy(id="RegisterModel_CountryID")
WebElement selectcountry;

public Select getCountrySelect() {
      return new Select(selectcountry);
    }

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"RegisterModel_Password\"]")
WebElement passwd;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"RegisterModel_ConfirmPassword\"]")
WebElement passwdconfirm;

@FindBy(id="RegisterModel_Postcode")
WebElement postcode;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"tabs-1\"]/div/div/div[16]/div/ins")
WebElement buttonno;





public WebElement button()
{
    return buttonno;
}

public WebElement Phone()
{
    return phone;
}


public WebElement PostCode()
{
    return postcode;
}


public WebElement City()
{
    return city; 
}


public WebElement FirstName()
{

return firstname;
}

public WebElement AddressOne()
{

return addressone;
}

public WebElement Addresstwo()
{

return addresstwo;
}


public WebElement SelectCount()
{

return selectcountry;
}

public WebElement Emailconfirm()
{

return emailconfirm;
}

public WebElement Email()
{

return email;
}

public WebElement Password()
{
    return passwd;
}


public WebElement Passwordconfirm()
{

return passwdconfirm;
}

public WebElement explicitWait() {
    WebDriverWait w=new WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 200);
    return w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(selectcountry)); 


}

}
```

Test Class

```
package testCases;

import pageFactory.ECUHomePage;
import pageFactory.ECUTestform;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TESTForm {
    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;


@Test
public void Test() throws InterruptedException
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.website.com/");
ECUHomePage rd = new ECUHomePage(driver);
ECUTestform rt = new ECUTestform(driver);
rd.TestForm().click();

// Name and Address 
rt.FirstName().sendKeys("TEST");
rt.AddressOne().sendKeys("TEST123");
rt.Addresstwo().sendKeys("TESTING3434");
rt.City().sendKeys("TESTINGTON");
rt.PostCode().sendKeys("TEST");

rt.explicitWait();

rt.getCountrySelect().selectByVisibleText("United Kingdom");
rt.Emailconfirm().sendKeys("test@testing.com");
rt.Email().sendKeys("test@testing.com");
rt.Password().sendKeys("testingpassword101");
rt.Passwordconfirm().sendKeys("password");
rt.Phone().sendKeys("0115 841003320");
rt.button().click();
```

I have tried at the bottom to create a web element to wait but I then declare it in the test class and it does not work. What would be the best way of adding a wait? I wish to declare a wait after the postcode box has been filled in

Comment: What error are you getting?  Would it be a NoSuchElementException?  The wait you have used requires a valid WebElement which needs to have been found in advance.  Have you tried with `w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("RegisterModel_CountryID")));`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494251/getting-elementnotinteractableexception-error-in-selenium-java/56523790#56523790

Comment: No error, the program just stops at rt.explicitWait(); or completely  ignores it  and yes i have just tried that

Comment: If this line is working `rt.getCountrySelect().selectByVisibleText("United Kingdom");` your wait is working.  What is the problem here, if you are getting no errors I'm failing to understand what the problem is

Comment: I don't understand it either, the wait does not initialize at all.. may i send you the program?

Comment: What is causing you a problem?  If you get no errors and the program works why do you think there is a problem?  I'm trying to get a stack trace out of you that will show me the issue you are struggling with.

Comment: how you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Create separate class called 'Explicitwait' and add all methods which are in WebDriverWait into this class with public static. Make sure to get driver, element and time in milliseconds as parameters.

Before that declare private static WebDriverWait wait;

Inside every method create an object for this wait variable like 'wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, milliseconds)'.
And second line should be wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)'.

After that call from your test class should be 'Explicitwait.methodName(driver, time in mills, element).
This will work for classes in your framework.